# Does the following pointer usage lead to undefined behavior?

Tags: c++, pointers

(I can't think of a more specific Title for my question, so it's currently generally stated)

Consider the following snippet

```
struct trie_node
{
    trie_node() : children(26) {};
    std::vector<std::shared_ptr<trie_node>> children;
};

int main()
{
    auto root = std::make_shared<trie_node>();
    root->children[0] = std::make_shared<trie_node>();
    root->children[0]->children[1] = std::make_shared<trie_node>();
    auto &ptr1 = root->children[0]->children[1];
    auto c1 = &root->children[0]->children[1];
    auto c2 = &root->children[0];
    *c1 = nullptr;
    std::cout << ptr1 << std::endl;
    *c2 = nullptr;
    std::cout << ptr1 << std::endl; 
}
```

When I execute this on my system, I get the following output:

```
0x0
0x37
```

Is appears the `*c2 = nullptr` somehow changed `ptr1` to no longer being equal to `nullptr`. I checked `ptr1 == nullptr` directly in the following snippet:

```
struct trie_node
{
    trie_node() : children(26) {};
    std::vector<std::shared_ptr<trie_node>> children;
};

int main()
{
    auto root = std::make_shared<trie_node>();
    root->children[0] = std::make_shared<trie_node>();
    root->children[0]->children[1] = std::make_shared<trie_node>();
    auto &ptr1 = root->children[0]->children[1];
    auto c1 = &root->children[0]->children[1];
    auto c2 = &root->children[0];
    *c1 = nullptr;
    std::cout << (ptr1 == nullptr) << std::endl;
    *c2 = nullptr;
    std::cout << (ptr1 == nullptr) << std::endl; 
}
```

and the output is

```
1
0
```

When I tried on [enter link description here](https://www.onlinegdb.com/online_c++_compiler), I get

```
1
1
```

Is the `std::cout << ptr1 << std::endl;` undefined behavior? Is it dereferencing a `nullptr` here, which I know would lead to undefined behavior, but I'm not positive that it's deferencing a `nullptr` here? It's not clear to me what it is doing.

`*c2 = nullptr` sets `root->children[0]` equal to `nullptr`. `ptr1` is a reference to `root->children[0]->children[1]`. So if I want to print `ptr`, am I trying to deference `root->children[0]` or is something else going on behind the scenes?

I should mention that I'm pretty sure `std::cout << ptr1 << std::endl;` is undefined behavior (I guess different outputs on different systems). I want to focus on the *why* part of it being undefined.

This issue leads me to another question if this problem is indeed deferencing a nullptr. How can we check, in this case, if we're about to deference a nullptr?

Comment: @Ruks What is the `std::shared_ptr<trie_node>*` here? Is it not set to `nullptr`?

Comment: @Ruks I'm pretty confused right now. The most recent deleted answer (I ca'nt see it anymore) seems to have said that the last print statement is not dereferencing anything. I just want to clarify that you are saying it IS dereferencing something?

Comment: @Ruks After reerading your second comment, I think we are referring to different things. You're referring to dereferencing `c1` and `c2`. I was referring to the last print statement when I asked if it's dereferencing something. I'm asking if `std::cout << ptr1 << std::endl` in itself is performing a dereference of `root->children[0]`.

Comment: @Ruks hmmm I see, but when I print, I do not get `0x0` for the second print. (I'll edit this into the OP)

Comment: Yes, it seems that I did misunderstand your question. The dereference itself is not undefined behavior but the second print statement is trying to print a destroyed `std::shared_ptr` object after you make `c2` refer to a `nullptr`.

Comment: Remove the aliasing and indirection: `root->children[0]->children[1] = nullptr; std::cout << root->children[0]->children[1]; root->children[0] = nullptr; std::cout << root->children[0]->children[1];`. Now it's obvious that the second output is undefined.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

When you do `*c2 = nullptr`, you destroy the object `root->children[0]`.  This in turn destroys the object `root->children[0]->children[1]`, since you've destroyed its parent. That means you have a reference to an object that no longer exists, and reading its value has undefined behavior, which means `0x37` is a perfectly valid output.

Comment: Is there a way to check that `ptr1` is destroyed? I mean I guess in this case you can just look at the code and see, but what if some of the stuff prior to the second print was in a black box?

Comment: If you changed `ptr1`'s type to `std::weak_ptr` you could safely check it to see if what it points to still exists or not.  (and of course if you changed it to `std::shared_ptr` then what it points to would exist for at least as long as `ptr1` did, and there would be no concerns about it being prematurely destroyed)

Comment: @JeremyFriesner Is there an analogous approach for raw pointers?

Comment: @24n8 no -- the only approach for raw pointers is to manually ensure (via the human-written design/logic in your program) that you do not dereference any pointer to an object after that object has been destroyed.  This is always going to be more error-prone than using smart-pointers to handle some or all of the necessary logic automatically, which is why smart-pointers are recommended over raw pointers in most cases.